# Update query in liquibase

Tags: oracle, liquibase

I need to run the below update query in liquibase, but I am not sure about the syntax. Can anyone please help:

```
update xyz.users
set email = (select CONCAT(username, '@gmail.com ') "email"
from xyz.users )
where email like '%@yahoo.com%'   ;
```

Comment: `(select CONCAT(username, '@gmail.com ') "email" from xyz.users )` could this part return many records instead of just one value and oracle does not know how to update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<update tableName="xyz.users">
    <column name="email" valueComputed="(select CONCAT(username, '@gmail.com ') 
from xyz.users)"/>
<where>email like '%@yahoo.com%'</where>
</update>
```

Comment: it throws error: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.

Comment: @ravikiran can you post your entire code..the error can be somewhere else..the format for update according to your above query is same what i posted here.

Comment: ignore my previous comments ... it worked fine. Thanks a ton.